# Cannot make changes to my Developer Story on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, developer-story

No changes made to my Developer Story are saving. Not editing an old job, nor newly adding an older one.

All fields autofill as they should.  The *Responsibilities* field claims "You're all set", and the dates look good.

But hitting Save does nothing.  Reload the page and no new job entry.  Click edit and no changes persist.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried updating your education? I was facing the same issue and completely ignored the education tab.

Comment: Adding an Education story worked.  Tried again with a Position and... nope, still no good.

Comment: can you share some snippets of your problem? It would be much clearer to understand the same